# Graphs and Krull-Schmidt Theorem

Tags: number-theory, graph-theory, category-theory

The book "Abstract Analytic Number Theory" of Knopfmacher states a similarity between Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic and categorical Krull-Schmidt Theorem. Essentially, it states that, in some categories satisfying this lemma, a version of Prime Number Theorem holds.

The book has many examples: finite groups, Riemannian manifolds, compact Lie groups and semisimple Lie algebras... and graphs. Of course, this book does not develop the case of graphs, but it says "(...) the category (class) of all *finite graphs* of a given interesting species; (...)" (cf. p. 21). Now, I'm learning about graphs and hypergraphs (I know a little; I admit this is not my specialization) and I find it very interesting, but I don't understand what "a given intesting species" means. I don't know if someone here would help me to clarify these words.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add more context, at least the full sentence of the book?

Comment: @Berci the complete sentence is: "A reader familiar with the Krul-Schmidt theorem for general algebraic systems wil no doubt by this stage have noticed many other examples of arithmetical categories. Amongst other interesting examples, one might perhaps also mention: (...) (xi) the category (class) of all _finite graphs_ of a given interesting species; et cetera. (Regarding (xi), one may note that morphisms other than isomorphisms are not often considered in the theory of graphs.)"

Comment: It has many other examples before the example of graphs, but none of the above is directly related with graphs. Now, an arithmetical category is a category $\mathcal{A}$ where Krull-Schmidt holds, endowed with a multiplicative ($N(A\times B)=N(A)N(B)$), positive function $N:\mathcal{A}\to\Bbb R$ such that $N^{-1}(x)$ is finite for all $x\in\Bbb R$.